# Spot the error in this induction

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

I'm learning induction. Spot the error in this induction:

Let $P(n): 1 = 2 = 3 = \dots = n$

It's true for $n = 1$, because $1 = 1$, then let's assume $P(n)$ is true *, so we must show that $P(n+1)$ is true. Summing $1$ on every element we will have: $2 = 3 = 4 \dots = n = n + 1$ **

Then, with * and **, we have that $P(n+1)$ is true.

I'm not enterly sure where's the error, but I think the error is in **, because we don't have $1 = n+1$, or maybe, because at the end we have $n = n+1$ that is false.

Well, if there's any missconcept or anything wrong in my thoughts please let me know.

Comment: $ \ P(n+1) \ $ should start from $ \ 1 \ , $ so adding $ \ 1 \ $ across the entire equation set  does _not_ produce the next proposition in the induction.

Comment: how to go from 1=1 to 1=2? the induction procedure should work at every step, and here it does not work for the first step

Comment: the problem is that *if* $n=1$ then $*$ plus $**$ do not give $p(n+1)$. \

Answer (score 2):

This is a disguised version of the famous "all horses are the same colour" proof. The induction step does not actually go through in every case; in particular, it fails if $n = 2$. As written, you have $1 = 1$, adding $1$ to this equation gives you... $2 = 2$. Not $2 = 1$ like you need to complete the argument.

Comment: More accurately, it's "all horses are the same color".

Comment: Thank you, corrected.

Comment: Here is an analysis of that particular fallacy: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/All_Horses_are_the_Same_Colour